# Why does BX get destroyed after a CALL?

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader

I'm writing some asm (x86_64) for a bootloader (16 bit real mode), and it seems like my registers get destroyed after a CALL.

My first file looks like so, roughly.

```
mov bx, 0x1234 ;moves 16 bits into the register BX (bl is ascii for "4")
call hexprint  ;call function
```

The function hexprint looks like so:

```
hexprint:
    mov ah, 0x0e  ;set bios to teletype mode
    mov al, bl    ;move the value from bl to al, (0x34)
    int 0x10      ;make bios print
    ret
```

however when I boot this into QEMU it does not print 4.

Some tests I've run are:

- doing `mov bx, 0x1234` in `printhex`. This works, and prints 4
- as in the code snippet, I have removed a `pusha` instruction from the very beginning of the function. My guess was that `push`es and `pusha` might delete or at least not be defined to maintain the value in the register after pushing to the stack, but that seems to not be the source of the issue.
- I have not yet tried this writing my own versions of `call` and `ret`

My current guess is that in my implementation of call, the registers are getting mangled, but I don't know how I'd fix that.

MRE:

boot_sect.asm

```
[org 0x7c00]

%include "hexprint.asm"

mov bx, 0x1234
call hexprint

jmp $ ; Jump forever.

; Padding and magic BIOS number.
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

hexprint.asm

```
hexprint:
    mov ah, 0x0e  ;set bios to teletype mode
    mov al, bl    ;move the value from bl to al, (0x34)
    int 0x10      ;make bios print
    ret
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that is known to exhibit the problem you have.  Your example is not self-contained as I can't assemble and run it as is.

Comment: does your bios require bh and/or bl to be setup for the call?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not in the function, it is in the way assembly works. The machine starts at the top of the file and works its way downwards. Including the file at the beginning of the file "runs" the contents immediately, causing much oddness to occur. Move the include statement to below the infinite loop but above the padding so that it is a) only accessable from a call, and b) not going to be beyond where the bootloader can look without setting up disk reading

Comment: And this is why we use debuggers, to make simple mistakes like this easy.  Single-stepping your bootloader would have shown execution starting at the first instruction (which comes from the included file) and put you on the right track quickly.  Next time please use a debugger before posting.  BOCHS has one built-in, or you can connect to QEMU as a GDB remote.  (If you're intentionally posting a self-answered question to share your knowledge / create a canonical duplicate for accidentally putting stuff in the path of execution, I'd recommend including a mention of using a debugger.)